# Changing the name of a blob received from server?

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob, fetch-api, pdf.js

Here is some code I'm using to get a PDF from my server and display it:

```
// Fetch a pdf file from the server and open it
fetch('/pdf')
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  .then(url => window.open(url))
```

Though this code works, it results in a random file name as you can see here:

[image: pdf]

Is there a way I can set a filename on this blob instead of that long string it's displaying?

BTW, I'm not trying to start a download with this, which is why I'm not just setting a `Content-Disposition` in my server.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `window.open(url)`. It's using the last segment of the URL as the name, which is the browser's ID for the `Blob`, and that can't be customized

Comment: why do you fetch/open instead of redirecting to that pdf?

Comment: This is a bit of a contrived example, I'm actually using `PDFJS` and passing the `url` to it which then displays the PDF in my webapp. So I need to keep the `fetch` structure. @slezica I don't really need to do `window.open`, but I still want to change the name since I'm getting a console warning from PDFJS saying the `name` is too long.